# Changing the margins of the achemso template

Tags: margins, geometry, achemso

The margin sizes provided by the achemso template are larger than what I need. I'd like to have leeway to change the margins as I desire, but using the geometry package leads to a clash for the geometry of the paper, indicating to me that achemso has immutable default margin sizes. I'm taking issue with the "immutable" part: I like achemso, it's served me well so far, but I'd be so happy if I were able to tamper a bit with the margins for compactness.

As a bonus, I'd highly appreciate a MWE demonstrating not only how to change the margins, but also how to customize them based on whether a page is odd or even (larger right margin for the even page, larger left margin for the odd page).

Comment: The class is purely for manuscript submissions to the ACS: what's the target for your document?

Comment: Definitely not the ACS. Target: my nitpicky TAs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things should mainly 'just work', though you may need to adjust the lengths used by `\maketitle`, *e.g.*

```latex
\documentclass{achemso}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin = 2in,a5paper}
\makeatletter
\setlength\acs@maketitle@width{\textwidth}
%\setlength\acs@space@pre@title{2em}
%\setlength\acs@space@post@title{1.5em}
%\setlength\acs@space@post@author{1em}
%\setlength\acs@space@post@address{1em}
%\setlength\acs@space@post@email{1.5em}
\makeatother
\title{Some things I did}
\author{A.N.~Other}
\email{a.n.other@edu.edu}
\affiliation{Some Edu}
\begin{document}

Hello world

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the class is _purely_ for submission to the ACS: I would strongly urge simply using `article` and adjusting as needed.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really see how this helps with customizing margin sizes. I could only get rid of the spaces near the title/author/email etc.

Comment: @TheRelentlessNucleophile I've added a margin change: my point was that you can set whatever you like using `geometry` after it's been loaded provided you do it using `\geometry` rather than as package options

Comment: I don't know how to thank you enough. This is exactly what I've been looking for. Please, accept my gratitude.